# How to invoke pydantic field_validator on another, optional field?

Tags: python, pydantic, pydantic-v2

I am trying to use a `field_validator` to validate a field based on the presence of another, optional field. So this is really about validating one input based on another input (the classic "password1/password2" tutorial case, albeit validating password1 on optional password2).

Example: If a given `plant='flower'`, then it must have a `color` (which is optional, because other plants may not have a color).

```
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel, field_validator
from pydantic_core.core_schema import FieldValidationInfo


class MyClass(BaseModel):

    plant: str
    color: Optional[str] = None

    @field_validator('plant')
    def flowers_have_color(cls, v, info: FieldValidationInfo):
        if v == 'flower':
            if info.data['color'] is None:
                raise ValueError("if 'plant' is a flower, it must have a color")
        return v
```

Expected behavior:

```
>>> MyClass(plant='tree')                # ok
MyClass(plant='tree', color=None)

>>> MyClass(plant='tree', color='red')   # ok
MyClass(plant='tree', color='red')

>>> MyClass(plant='flower')              # raise

>>> MyClass(plant='flower', color='red') # ok
MyClass(plant='flower', color='red')
```

This raises the following error:

```
MyClass(plant='flower', color='red')
>> KeyError: 'color'
```

While the above code invokes the field_validator when passing a "flower" plant (as expected), it does not see the `color` inside the validator, because the `color` is `Optional`. Indeed we see

```
print(info.data.keys())
dict_keys([])
```

How can I make the optional field `color` available to the field_validator (in general, or at least if it is provided)?

EDIT: As per comment below (thanks to Yurii Motov) this can be solved by using a `model_validator` (see below). But seems like an overkill to me, given I really just want to validate a single field (no need for `self`, classmethods or objects, etc.), and anything needed for that validation is input to the class constructor. It feels weird that `field_validator` would not be able to work in this situation - and vice versa, if validating "any input against another input" were not to be possible with `field_validator`, then why have it in pydantic in the first place and not replace any and all `field_validator`s by `model_validator`s?

```
@model_validator(mode='after')
def plants_must_have_color(self):
    if self.plant == 'flower':
        if self.color is None:
            raise ValueError("'flower' must have a color")
    return self
```

Comment: You need `model_validator` instead of `field_validator`

Comment: Understood. But then, why do we have `field_validators` left over in pydantic v2 at all, in the first place? Seems like I can refactor every `field_validator` (on a single field `v`) to a `model_validator` on `self.v`, no? Why not replace all `validators` from pydantic 1 with `model_validator`s?

Comment: Just two different options

Comment: Thanks! I edited the question. And it does work. But indeed, the 2 fields required (`plant` and `color` are "input only", strictly). So I am still wondering whether `field_validator` should not work here.. and if it doesn't whether it's not obsoletely entirely, and everthing can just better be solved by `model_validator`s. Or, in other words: what's the need for pydantic to have a `field_validator` in general, then?